# JFrame not "disposing" on actionperformed method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

**Background:** I am creating a login browser page before my main UI(myGUI) page is displayed. I am using a HashMap to store the correct username and password combinations. The key is put in a getter method where I then access it from the LoginBrowser class constructor, where I build the actual UI.

**Problem:** Currently, the key values are stored correctly and login is successful. It properly loads up the main UI after the correct credentials are entered. I tried to instantiate the class with the key inside and then call the dispose method. However, the login browser UI does not go away afterwards. What is wrong with my instantiation and how would I solve it?

**My current code:**

***Main method:***

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
       IdAndPasswords s = new IdAndPasswords();        

       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               LoginBrowser lb = new LoginBrowser(s.getInfo());
                lb.setVisible(true);
                //myGUI.requestFocusInWindow(); // makes sure textfield or other components don't auto focus on start-up
                lb.setTitle("Chat App");
                lb.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        }); 
    }
```

***Login Browser Class Contructor:***

```
 HashMap<String,String> loginInfo = new HashMap<String,String>();

/**
 * Creates new form LoginBrowser
 * @param loginOG
 */
public LoginBrowser(HashMap<String,String> loginOG) {

    initComponents();
    this.loginInfo = loginOG;
 
}
```

***Login Browser Action Performed method:***

```
/*
If login button to perform actions
when pressed
*/
private void loginBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(evt.getSource()==loginBtn) {
       String userIDNew = usernameText.getText(); // get text of JTextfield
       String passwordNew = String.valueOf(passwordText.getPassword()); // get text of JPasswordfield and convert
       
    if(loginInfo.containsKey(userIDNew)) { // key
         // if entered characters in strings match up, 
         // display message and get rid of login browser
        if(loginInfo.get(userIDNew).equals(passwordNew)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Login successful");
            IdAndPasswords s = new IdAndPasswords();         
            LoginBrowser lb = new LoginBrowser(loginInfo);
            lb.dispose(); // dispose login browser
    // Once old form is disposed, open main gui form
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myGUI myGUI = new myGUI(userIDNew);
            myGUI.setVisible(true);
            //myGUI.requestFocusInWindow(); // makes sure textfield or other components don't auto focus on start-up
            myGUI.setTitle("Chat App");
            myGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    });
        // tell user if info entered is incorrect
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Incorrect Password");
           }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Incorrect Username");
       }        
   }
}
```

Comment: You create a new `LoginBrowser lb` (which you never set visible) and call `dispose()` on that. It's not the same `LoginBrowser` as the one you created earlier.

Comment: How would I make the instantiation accessible to both classes?

Comment: Just call `dispose()` directly or `this.dispose()`

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you very much! I originally coded the UI without the design feature and changing over caused me a couple issues like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating class with key:

```
  LoginBrowser lb = new LoginBrowser(loginInfo);
   lb.dispose(); // dispose login browser
```

Simply use this. to control JFrame from within design feature of netbeans:

```
this.dispose();
```